# SQL - Getting previous row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the monthly OpenPipe value as for first month `Openpipe+Newpipe-ClosingDeal` and then for other month it should take the previous months value and add `newpipe-closingDeal` to it.

I tried

```sql
select Year, Month, NewPipe, ClosingDeal, OpenPipe, MonthlyOpenPipe
, lag(MonthlyOpenPipe) OVER (ORDER BY year, month) + NewPipe -  ClosingDeal
From TB1
```

but because there is no data for other months except Jan 2022 for OpenPipe, I am getting `NULL`. I want the previous month value of MonthlyOpenPipe to be forwarded and used for this month's calculation.

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please (next time) post your example data as TEXT, not as IMAGE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use coalesce(). You didn't tag your backend, use whatever it is in your backend if coalesce() is not supported:

```
select Year, Month, NewPipe, ClosingDeal, OpenPipe, MonthlyOpenPipe ,
 coalesce(lag(MonthlyOpenPipe) OVER (ORDER BY year, month), 0) 
   + NewPipe - ClosingDeal 
From TB1
```

Comment: Thankyou, its SQL server, tried coalesce, but its doesnt carry forward the calculation, it gives same 0/p as prevvalue (with the number of monthly openpipe for feb and everything else as 0 )

Comment: @user17588153, I didn't say it would carry over your calculation or your calculation is right. You were asking how to prevent it from showing null. Your question had nothing about carrying over the calculation. Please rephrase your question to explain what you want rather than what you think is the solution (XY problem). Also please provide sample data (as Text of course not a picture , and preferably as a dbfiddle) and desired output.